# Shopify - Change size variant from select dropdown to buttons

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I would like to change my variant display from dropdown (select) to using buttons instead. I cannot find any up to date guides elsewhere online. I am using the Debut shopify theme.

it currently looks like this [dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZduGO.png) but I want to change this to buttons with the sizes. i.e. so you click your desired size button and then click the standard 'add to cart' button (which is already in place, but currently for the dropdown) below it.

Here is the code:

```
          {% capture "form_classes" -%}
            product-form product-form-{{ section.id }}
            {%- unless section.settings.show_variant_labels %} product-form--hide-variant-labels {% endunless %}
            {%- if section.settings.enable_payment_button and product.has_only_default_variant %} product-form--payment-button-no-variants {%- endif -%}
            {%- if current_variant.available == false %} product-form--variant-sold-out {%- endif -%}
          {%- endcapture %}

          {% form 'product', product, class:form_classes, novalidate: 'novalidate', data-product-form: '' %}
            {% unless product.has_only_default_variant %}
              <div class="product-form__controls-group">
                {% for option in product.options_with_values %}
                  <div class="selector-wrapper js product-form__item">
                    <label {% if option.name == 'default' %}class="label--hidden" {% endif %}for="SingleOptionSelector-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
                      {{ option.name }}
                    </label>
                    <select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-{{ section.id }} product-form__input"
                      id="SingleOptionSelector-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
                      data-index="option{{ forloop.index }}"
                    >

                      {% for value in option.values %}
                        <option value="{{ value | escape }}"{% if option.selected_value == value %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </select>

                  </div>

                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            {% endunless %}

            <select name="id" id="ProductSelect-{{ section.id }}" class="product-form__variants no-js">
              {% for variant in product.variants %}
                <option value="{{ variant.id }}"
                  {%- if variant == current_variant %} selected="selected" {%- endif -%}
                >
                  {{ variant.title }}  {%- if variant.available == false %} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}{% endif %}
                </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>

            {% if section.settings.show_quantity_selector %}
              <div class="product-form__controls-group">
                <div class="product-form__item">
                  <label for="Quantity-{{ section.id }}">{{ 'products.product.quantity' | t }}</label>
                  <input type="number" id="Quantity-{{ section.id }}"
                    name="quantity" value="1" min="1" pattern="[0-9]*"
                    class="product-form__input product-form__input--quantity" data-quantity-input>
                </div>
              </div>
            {% endif %}

            <div class="product-form__error-message-wrapper product-form__error-message-wrapper--hidden{% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %} product-form__error-message-wrapper--has-payment-button{% endif %}"
              data-error-message-wrapper
              role="alert"
            >
              <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.error' | t }} </span>
              {% include 'icon-error' %}
              <span class="product-form__error-message" data-error-message>{{ 'products.product.quantity_minimum_message' | t }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="product-form__controls-group product-form__controls-group--submit">
              <div class="product-form__item product-form__item--submit
                {%- if section.settings.enable_payment_button %} product-form__item--payment-button {%- endif -%}
                {%- if product.has_only_default_variant %} product-form__item--no-variants {%- endif -%}"
              >
                <button type="submit" name="add"
                  {% unless current_variant.available %} aria-disabled="true"{% endunless %}
                  aria-label="{% unless current_variant.available %}{{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}{% else %}{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}{% endunless %}"
                  class="btn btn--rounded product-form__cart-submit{% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %} btn--secondary-accent{% endif %}"
                  data-add-to-cart>
                  <span data-add-to-cart-text>
                    {% unless current_variant.available %}
                      {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
                    {% else %}
                      {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
                    {% endunless %}
                  </span>
                  <span class="hide" data-loader>
                    {% include 'icon-spinner' %}
                  </span>
                </button>
                {% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %}
                  {{ form | payment_button }}
                {% endif %}
              </div>
            </div>
          {% endform %}
        </div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace your select boxes with input radio buttons:

```
{%- for variant in product.variants -%}         
<input 
  type="radio" 
  name="id" 
  class="variant-option"
  value="{{ variant.id }}" 
  id="variant-option-{{ variant.id }}" 
  {% unless variant.available %} disabled{% endunless %}
  {% if product.selected_variant.id == variant.id %} checked{% endif %}
>
<label for="variant-option-{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }}</label>
{%- endfor -%}
```

And then just add some styles to display these inputs as buttons e.g:

```
.variant-option + label {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.variant-option:checked + label {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.variant-option[disabled] + label {
  opacity: 0.5;  
}
.variant-option {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: I use theme Default, the file to modify is product-template.liquid.  Thanks for your help